# cant connect to my iis7 hosted site on my mobile in the same network

Tags: iis-7.5

I am using windows `7 Ultimate` and `iis7.5`. I just created a site called `steel.com` and added it in to the host file like `127.0.0.1 steel.com`.

It works fine on my local computer.
When I try to connect from another device (from my phone), nothing shows.

I connected those devices using hotspot from my laptop with `baidu` wifi hotspot.
I checked windows firewall.
I have added http rule and https rule
My site uses https protocol (steel.com).

Any idea what might be the issue?

Comment: I assume you're developing this site, and hosting it temporarily on your work computer. The host file is only consulted by the computer on which it is stored. You would need to find a way to instruct your phone to resolve "steel.com" to the ip of your IIS on the LAN (e.g. 192.168.x.y). If your phone is using the hotspot as the DNS server, then there is a possibility that the firmware on your hotspot device/router allows you to set custom DNS entries -- in which case, add an entry for steel.com pointing to your IIS's IP. Another option is to http-proxy into your server from the phone.

Comment: Thanks, hope helps